RVIZ on remote server, ssh x forwarding
I have connected to the remote server by ssh. Both of my local and remote machines are Ubuntu20.04. So when I run rviz command I get the following error:
[ WARN] [1716361265.827075520]: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 61)
rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at /build/ogre-1.9-kiU5_5/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 61)
[ERROR] [1716361265.827149573]: Unable to create the rendering window after 100 tries.
[ INFO] [1716361265.827171026]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

Can anyone help me with this?
The weirdest thing is that rviz used to work properly 2-3 weeks ago. I am not sure what exactly I messed up since then.
Update.
My troubleshooting history:

xeyes command working properly
added user to video group, didn't help
When I physically connect a monitor to a remote machine, rviz can be launched successfully. So I guess the issue is about the SSH connection to the remote machine.


Special thanks to Bourumir Wyngs for fruitful feedback.
I have actually updated Nvidia Driver a week ago. Since the monitor is not usually plugged into the server I have used sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall command (the second method from this article). After that, I didn't experience any issues with Nvidia Driver, cause all of my PyTorch codes that require GPU were running properly. Therefore, I thought the rviz error was more about the SSH connection. Thanks to Bourumir Wyngs' comment, I have updated the Nvidia Driver using Gnome GUI(the first method from this article). It solved my issue.

Looks like OGRE cannot establish an OpenGL context, which it needs for rendering any graphics. This could be due incompatible graphics drivers, incorrect OpenGL configuration, unsupported OpenGL version or just attempting to use the text only login as X session (you need ssh -X or ssh -Y to launch RViz remotely).
Try
glxinfo | grep 'OpenGL version'

This may give more insights, especially if does not work outright. glxinfo is part of the mesa-utils.
If, as you say, it stopped working without obvious reason, I suspect that something has been updated (kernel, driver) and OpenGL does not longer work as expected.
The error literally means that C++ cannot create a string from the null pointer but that does not sound very useful.

Since uploading the post, I have been working on it. I have updated the original post my the troubleshooting history. Running command glxinfo | grep 'OpenGL version' returns following error       X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)   Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)   Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)   Value in failed request:  0x0   Serial number of failed request:  66   Current serial number in output stream:  67

This means OpenGL installation is broken. Check if the GPU driver is ok.

Thank you so much, that solves the issue.

@KnK - If this answer fixed your issue, please upvote and mark the answer as the accepted answer. Also, please take the [tour] to better understand how Stack Exchange operates.
